# Email Notification to Store Owner When Order Complete

Tags: 8, commerce

During early development I had it working so the store owner would get an email when an order was completed. I just realized this isn't working anymore. Where are the settings related to this? Is it supposed to use the store's email, or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Unfortunately that's a too-broad question and therefore doesn't fit for Drupal Answers. Which is more of a knowledge repo in form of a Q+A. Question with detailed information, answers to fix the problem, accept the correct answer. Drupal Answers is no forum. You have a question and need to provide all steps to reproduce the problem, explaining what you did yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck. We can't search all settings on your site for you and we won't start a back-and-forth discussion to clarify what exactly you've done. Instead you need to tell us.

Comment: You can go to `admin/commerce/config/order-types` and modify your order type(s) and select *Email the customer a receipt when an order is placed* and add an email address in the *Send a copy of the receipt to this email* field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the versions so I assume you are using Drupal 8 with Commerce 2.

You can use [Commerce Reaction](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reactions) module as it allows you to select the Commerce event and have a reaction when it is dispatched.

It provides a plugin to send HTML, and twig template emails with nice integration with the Token module.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This sounds like exactly what I need.

Comment: Commerce Reaction is not covered by the security advisory policy.